# TextField in UITable Scroll on KeyBoard

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll, textfield

I have `UITextField` in `UITableView` and When I am clicking on the `UITextField` then I have moved the offset, But My Question is when the user scroll to next field then it show 
weird behaviour some time input refreshes or the focus will return to previous `UITextField`.

Comment: @user321373: As Jhaliya said accept some answers and I am the one edit your question and i still did not get your problem please rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

See this code and impelement According ur project

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

  [self scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:textField];
  return YES;
  }
- (void)scrollViewToCenterOfScreen:(UIView *)theView {
  CGFloat viewCenterY = theView.center.y;
  CGRect applicationFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];

  CGFloat availableHeight = applicationFrame.size.height - 200;            // Remove area covered by keyboard

  CGFloat y = viewCenterY - availableHeight / 2.0;
  if (y < 0) {
      y = 0;
  }
  [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, y) animated:YES];

}

-(BOOL) textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{

```
if ([textField isEqual:txtStAppField])
{
    [txtStConfirmField becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([textField isEqual:txtStConfirmField])
{
    [txtDummyAppField becomeFirstResponder];
}
else if ([textField isEqual:txtStConfirmField])
{
    [txtDummyConfirmFeild becomeFirstResponder];
}
else 
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];       
    [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
}

return YES;
```

}

//
txtStConfirmField,txtDummyConfirmFeild,txtDummyAppField,txtStConfirmField,txtStConfirmField are tectField name.